# Save image from url with curl and file_put_contents PHP

Tags: php, image, curl, html-escape-characters

i want to save a picture from a remote server to my site. 
I create the text in the TinyMCE editor and insert the image from the remote server there. Next, I need to save this picture to my server.
To do this, i get a link to the picture from the text:

```php
    preg_match('/<img(.*)src(.*)=(.*)"(.*)"/U', $text, $result);
    $url =  array_pop($result);
```

Next through curl and `file_put_contents` i get the file and copy to my server.

```php
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: image/jpeg';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  $url ) ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; 
    Windows NT 5.0)");
    $image = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    file_put_contents('myfolder/image.jpg', $url);
```

As a result, not a picture is created, but a text file 'myfolder/image.jpg' with a size of 16 kb with text - Bad URL timestamp.

```
curl_getinfo returns [content_type] => text/plain [http_code] => 403
```

But, in case i am assigning `$url` manually in `CURLOPT_URL`, for example

```php
$url = 'https://scontent.ftbs4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/39900479_1856467244440953_5986986678919626752_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=6262ebe636e7328f0471af2820fd4050&oe=5C03BEC7'
```

then the file is successfully copied.

```
curl_getinfo returns [content_type] => image/jpeg [http_code] => 200
```

Where did I do wrong?

This `$_POST`:

```
Array ( 
  [id] => 143
  [title] => Topic
  [description] => description
  [text] => <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> </head> <body> <p>Hello</p> <p><img src="https://scontent.ftbs4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/39900479_1856467244440953_5986986678919626752_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&amp;oh=6262ebe636e7328f0471af2820fd4050&amp;oe=5C03BEC7" alt="" width="776" height="776" /></p> </body> </html>
)
```

full php code

```php
<?php 
//print_r($_POST);

preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$_POST['text'] , $result); 

foreach($result  as $img_tag){
foreach( $img_tag as $tag){   
preg_match('/<img(.*)src(.*)=(.*)"(.*)"/U', $tag, $regexResult);
$img_link = array_pop($regexResult);
$file_name = basename($img_link);

//$img_link = 'https://scontent.ftbs4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/39900479_1856467244440953_5986986678919626752_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=6262ebe636e7328f0471af2820fd4050&oe=5C03BEC7';

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: image/jpeg';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  $img_link ) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");                                                                   
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$targetPath = '/folder/'.$_POST['id'].'/';

file_put_contents($targetPath.$file_name, $html);
}}  
?>
```

Comment: I would dump the `$url` variable you get with the regex extraction and compare it to the working URL you posted. Are they exactly the same?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After regex extraction I get absolutely the same url. I copy url after extraction and insert into the $url value, and it works.

Comment: Can you provide the `$text` (HTML with img) so I can try to reproduce it with the full code?

Comment: I edited the question. added a $_POST  request and a php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$_POST` the content of the `img src` is coming in with certain special characters like `&` encoded as `&amp;`.

If you open this URL in the browser, you get the same error: `https://scontent.ftbs4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/39900479_1856467244440953_5986986678919626752_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&amp;oh=6262ebe636e7328f0471af2820fd4050&amp;oe=5C03BEC7`.

You can reverse this escaping using [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html-entity-decode). If I change this line the curl works:

```php
$img_link = html_entity_decode(array_pop($regexResult));
```

Comment: Mind to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) then? You can do that even below 15rep (upvote).